# Cannot load Member object from xml file to arraylist

Tags: java, xml

I have a registry for members of a club and I have been successful when saving the members to an xml file through the code:

```
public void saveToRegistry() throws IOException {

    if (memberList.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("Sorry, you do not have any members in the Registry to Save!");
    }

    else {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        try {
            JAXBContext context;
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Member.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++) {

                marshaller.marshal(memberList.get(i), out);
            }

            System.out.print("Your members have successfully been Saved in C:\\Users");
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and my Member Class is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Member")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "persNum", "id", "numOfBoats", "boats", "boat"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)


public class Member {

@XmlElement(name = "MemberName")
private String name;
@XmlElement(name = "PersonalNumber")
private String persNum;
@XmlElement(name = "IdentityNumber")
private String id;
@XmlElement(name = "NumberofBoats")
private int numOfBoats;
@XmlElement(name = "BoatInfo")
private ArrayList<Boat> boats = new ArrayList<Boat>();
@XmlElement(name = "Boat")
private Boat boat;


public Member() {}

public Member(String memberName, String memberPersNum) {
    this.name = memberName;
    this.persNum = memberPersNum;
}
//Member ID is the first letter of the name plus the last three numbers of their personal number.
public String createID() {
    id = getName().substring(0, 1) + getPersNum().substring(7, 10); //needs a dash when making the personal number


    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPersNum() {
    return persNum;
}

public void setPersNum(String persNum) {
    this.persNum = persNum;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getNumOfBoats() {
    return numOfBoats;
}

public void setNumOfBoats(int numOfBoats) {
    this.numOfBoats = numOfBoats;
}

public Boat getBoat() {
    return boat;
}

public void setBoat(Boat boat) {
    this.boat = boat;
}

 public String toString(){
     String temp = 
             "\nMember: "  + this.name + " "
                 + "\nMember ID: " + this.id
                 + " " + "\nPersonal Number: " + this.persNum
                 + " " + "\nNumber of Boats: " + this.numOfBoats
                 +"\n";
         return temp;
}
```

}

However when trying to load the members from the file using the code:

```
public void loadFromRegistry() throws FileNotFoundException, JAXBException {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Member.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    Member emps = (Member) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    for (Member mem : getMembers()) {
        memberList.add(mem);
        System.out.println(mem.getName());
        System.out.println(mem.getPersNum());
    }
}


public ArrayList<Member> getMembers() {
    return memberList;
}
```

my output gives the error that:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Pranav/Member%20Registry.txt; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.]
```

If someone could tell what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: JAXB only want to read Xml-Files. Just use a different filename like "member_registry.xml".

Comment: now that is working but now nothing is being printed out when loading the object... and there is an error when loading more than one object that says:

    Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Pranav/Member_Registry.txt; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.]